# How could socket.recv(256) return None?

Tags: python, sockets

Having 2 python programs , `host1.py` and `host2.py`  which run simultaneously and communicate via `socket` such that -

`host1.py` has `reciveSock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)`

and `host2.py` has `sendSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)` .

Both the socket's are binding each other  .

At `host1.py` has  -

```
try:
    msgBacked = reciveSock.recv(256)
except:
    pass
if( msgBacked is None):
    print "isNone!"
```

And indeed it prints `isNone!` mean `msgBacked` is a `None`  .

All the send's from `host2.py` to `host1.py` are in a type `sendSocket.send("ACK")` so that there is a value in the sent string which tranported to `host1.py` .

So how this `msgBacked` could be `None` ?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `try/except`?

Comment: @DavidWolever : `msgReturn = reciveSock.recv(256)
socket.timeout: timed out`

Comment: And **THIS** is **EXACTLY** why `try: ... except: pass` is *the* single most horrible thing you can do in Python! And what's up with those `()` in your if statement? It's python, not <some other language>! Please.. no Python developer wants to see parentheses there!

Comment: There's your problem ;) For more on why `except:` is bad: http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely `receiveSock.recv` is [throwing a timeout exception](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout), and `msgBacked` was previously set to `None`. Try removing the `try .. except` and see what happens.